# Unable to load plugin for transport 'image_transport/compressed_sub'

Tags: ros, compressed-image-transport, image-transport

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using Kinect on Ubuntu 16.04.

After executing

```
rosrun image_view extract_images image_transport/compressed_sub
```

I get

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'image_transport::TransportLoadException'
what():  Unable to load plugin for transport 'image_transport/compressed_sub', error string:
According to the loaded plugin descriptions the class image_transport/image_transport/compressed_sub_sub with base class type image_transport::SubscriberPlugin does not exist. Declared types are  image_transport/compressedDepth_sub image_transport/compressed_sub image_transport/raw_sub image_transport/theora_sub
Aborted (core dumped)
```

What surprises me is the name of the class, which seems to me a little redundant.
**image_transport/image_transport/compressed_sub_sub**
instead of
**image_transport/compressed_sub**

Is this maybe be a bug?

EDIT:
I do have compressed_image_transport installed

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/270881/unable-to-load-plugin-for-transport-%27image_transport/compressed_sub%27/) by [cduguet](https://answers.ros.org/users/1941/cduguet/) on ROS Answers with karma: 187 on 2017-09-14

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I needed to install image_transport_plugins

The fix for ubuntu users:

```
apt install ros-${ROS_DISTRO}-image-transport-plugins
```

---

Originally posted by [Link](https://answers.ros.org/users/483/link/) with karma: 228 on 2019-11-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MBD](https://answers.ros.org/users/80689/mbd/) on 2021-08-24**:
thanks a lot. that helped

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey, for anyone having the same problem:

I just fixed it by renaming the topic i publish the CompressedImage on to 'XXX/XXX/compressed'

It seems like the overall structure as well as the '/compressed' at the end of the topic name is important.

Hope it helps someone.

---

Originally posted by [Sidet](https://answers.ros.org/users/72458/sidet/) with karma: 31 on 2021-04-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [yipai](https://answers.ros.org/users/119053/yipai/) on 2022-09-26**:
Thank you bro, you saved my life.